# Chrome in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, google-chrome, 12.10

It seems like Chrome isn't ready for Ubuntu 12.10 yet, as you get the error when trying to install it, should I install Chromium instead, or just stick with Firefox for a bit?

The only problem is, I like using the Chrome web apps. I have a nice clean install of 12.10, and don't want to mess it up with some dodgy installs already.

Comment: Adding the error your question would help!

Comment: writing this from 12.10 using chrome browser...Just go to chrome site and download deb file install it via gdebi manager

Comment: maybe you consider to go through the procedure to get this reopened, because as I commented on Elirans answer, there is a stable PPA for convenient setup via commandline or the Software Center ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Google Chrome is a proprietary application it will never be available in Ubuntu repository, but you can install the Chromium web browser that also support the Google Chrome apps and you can also access the Chrome Web Store from it.

To install Chromium run the following command at the Terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

To install Google Chrome go to http://www.google.com/ and search for "Get Google Chrome"

Answer (score 1):

Chromium provides almost the same experience and same UI as Chrome, and it also allows you to change the theme and install web apps.  So you can install Chromium instead of Chrome. I think that there's no Chrome for linux system.

Comment: Xzen, there **is** Chrome for Linux. I'm using it.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Im in china so its kinda hard to get info about google. But anyways, they're almost the same

Answer (score 0):

Chromium has the same web-app creation feature as chrome.

Comment: Although I must admit that it doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.10 - the .desktop file it creates does not start the app. Hope it's just temporary, as I use many chromium web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with Chromium, it's quite easy to install (e.g. via Software Center), and there's no setup needed - it will sync with your user data much like any other Chrome distribution and you can access your bookmarks, web apps etc..

Note, however, that Chromium needs to be updated manually (unlike Chrome), but that easy - just run the Update Manager once in a while and you're good to go. Other than that, it's pretty much identical to Chrome.

Comment: Okay, I have never used Chromium, how different is it to Chrome? Does it look alright in Ubuntu, because I used Chrome in 12.04, and have just realised how clunky it looks compared to the built in FF.

Comment: see the updated answer (basically the same as Chrome for end users).

Comment: If you want Chroome (and why not?) you can use a PPA to install:

Comment: use "wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -" to get the key for the PPA

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

Comment: then follow with the usual "sudo apt-get update", "sudo aptget upgrade", and finally "sudo apt-get google-chrome-stable" -- that's it!

Comment: I'd love to elaborate but this thread has been closed, so I can't really answer officially but I hope you get it done ... cya

Comment: sorry there's a typo above: it's never "aptget" it's always "apt-get" - just for your information ... the last one is "sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable" , I missed the "install above", well, sry, cya